# Maximum size in bytes of single 16 bit character in UTF-7 representation

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-7

What would be maximum size in bytes of single UTF-16 character (2-byte character i.e. `char` type in .NET) saved in UTF-7 format?

This is what I've found on Wikipedia:

> 5 for an isolated case inside a run of single byte characters. For
>   runs 2 2⁄3 per character plus padding to make it a whole number of
>   bytes plus two to start and finish the run

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unicode_encodings#Seven-bit_environments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a *single* UTF-16 code unit, the only number you need to pay attention to in there is **5**.

Essentially, in [UTF-7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7), characters not within its "safe" alphabet 
are converted to UTF-16 and then that is converted to [modified Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#UTF-7). With a single UTF-16 code unit, it is converted into 2 2/3 Base64 units then padded to a full 3. An escape character is added at the beginning and possibly the end to signify it as a UTF-7 sequence, resulting in a maximum of 5 bytes.